# Linear varieties of dimension 1 can be rationally parametrized

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $L\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ be a linear subvariety i.e. $L=\mathbb{V}(F_1,\ldots,F_r)$ for some homogeneous polynomials $F_i$ of degree 1.

Choose two distinct points in $L,$ say $a=(a_0:\ldots:a_n)$ and $b=(b_0:\ldots:b_n).$

I want to show that, if $L$ has dimension 1, then the map $\mathbb{P}^1\to L$ given by 
$$(\lambda:\mu) \longmapsto (\lambda a_0+\mu b_0: \ldots : \lambda a_n+\mu b_n)$$
is surjective (in particular, we see that $L$ can be rationally parametrized).

But I'm completely stuck and would really appreciate a prod in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can really do this using linear algebra. So first of all notice that, assuming you choose a minimal set for the linear homogeneous $F_i$, then $r=n-1$. Then if you think them as polynomials in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}$, what is the dimension of the solution space?

PS. You said you just want a hint, so tell me if you need more details.

Comment: Well if we have $n-1$ linearly independent equations in $n+1$ variables, then the solution space in $k^{n+1}$ has dimension 2. But I don't see how this helps sorry?

Comment: And what is the dimension of the image of the map you want to prove that is surjective?

Comment: Ah ok - I see what you mean. I guess what I'm struggling with is interpreting the map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to L$ as a linear map...?

Comment: You need to pass appropriately everything to affine spaces and then it should work.